# Not printing a certain element in loop

Tags: java

So I have the following piece of code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the upper limit: ");
        int input = reader.nextInt();

        int i = 0;
        int power = 1;
        long sum;

        while (i <= input) {
            System.out.print(power + " + ");
            sum = power + power;
            power = power * 2;
            i++;

            if (power > input) {
                System.out.print(" = " + sum);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lets say the user inputs 500.

The output would be:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 64 + 128 + 256 + = 512
```

I want to get rid of the last "+" so it looks like an actual equation.

Comment: simply change the line once ==>.  System.out.print( power + (power * 2<= input?" + ":""));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate your string and then chop it off, instead of printing it. I altered your while loop so it does exactly that:

```
...
StringBuilder powerLine = new StringBuilder();
while (i <= input) {

    powerLine.append(power + " + ");
    //System.out.print(power + " + ");

    sum = power + power;
    power = power * 2;

    i++;

    if (power > input) {
        System.out.print(powerLine.substring(0, powerLine.length() - 3));
        System.out.print(" = " + sum);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print and increment `power` outside of the loop, and then reverse the order you print:

```
System.out.print(power++);
while (i <= input)
{

   System.out.print(" + " + power );
   //...
}
```

Which will output:

```
Enter the upper limit: 
500
1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 + 128 + 256 = 51
```

Comment: I do no want to display the first iteration of power twice. I.E in your example "1 + 1"

Answer (score 1):

Just add printing `+` in else statement

```
 Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the upper limit: ");
    int input = reader.nextInt();

    int i = 0;
    int power = 1;
    long sum;

    while (i <= input) {
        System.out.print(power);
        sum = power + power;
        power = power * 2;
        i++;

        if (power > input) {
            System.out.print(" = " + sum);
            System.exit(0);
        }else {
            System.out.print(" + ");
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 + 128 + 256 = 512
```

Answer (score 0):

simply change the line only like below

> System.out.print( power + (power * 2<= input?" + ":""));